GameMaker. Несколько спрайтов для одного объекта
В рамках хакатона я взялась реализовать игру на GameMaker, с которым до этого не имела никаких дел. Сейчас делаю платформер-сегмент, где нужно исправлять "плохой" код(убирать лишние знаки и в таком духе).
Я остановилась на том, чтобы сделать каждую букву кода отдельным блоком так скажем, так как нужна возможность разрушать единичные символы.
И вот возник вопрос: есть ли какой то способ не создавать 30+ объектов под каждый символ? Есть ли какой-то способ просто накидывать текстуры при создании каждого отдельного объекта?

